# Using the print command and the cmd module?

Tags: python, shell, cmd

In my Python application, I have a command prompt using the `cmd` module. I also have a thread running in the background, that occasionally prints messages when it needs to. However, this causes conflicts. The message will print where a user would typically input a command. For example, the application will typically start with the prompt (in my case, `$`). When the background thread prints a message, it is printed after the prompt, leaving us with something like this:

```
$ This is a test message!
(Command typed by a user will end up here)
```

If a user enters a command, it will still work fine, but can be very confusing. Instead, I would like to print a line above, so that we have this:

```
This is a test message!
$ (Command typed by a user will end up here)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use curses for this ... here is a simple example

**curses_test.py**

```
import curses
try:
   w = curses.initscr()
   w.addstr(5,5,"Hello         ")
   w.addch(7,5,">")
   w.addstr(6,6,w.getstr(7,7))
   w.getch()
finally:
   curses.endwin()
```

it should just exist if you are using linux ... windows can be difficult to install it on

Comment: Sadly I'm targeting a Windows audience, so I don't believe this will work for me.

Comment: then you should use a gui .... (windows does have ncurses ... but your right it is much much harder)